# How many blocks can you place on a slope?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

How many 6 cm wide, 2 cm thick blocks can you place on a 30 degree slope with friction so that the block tower does not collapse?

[image]

I try to solve the problem by using conservation of momentum and find that whether the tower fell or not does not depends on the height of the tower but it depends on the amount of friction exerted on the tower, I am certain that I am wrong because I assume that the block don't have width. I don't know whether I do it the right way so can anyone please explain to me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the friction is always sufficient to stop the blocks from sliding, then you need to consider the direction of the moments of the various forces involved about the bottom edge of the lowest block, where it meets the plane. If the moment of the weight of the blocks acts anticlockwise about this point then the tower will topple. The weight of the tower of blocks can be taken to be a single vector acting through the centre of gravity of the whole tower, and the position of the tower's centre of gravity will move to the left as more blocks are added to the tower.

The importance of the dimensions of the blocks is that it allows you to calculate the position of the tower's centre of gravity (assuming each block has the same weight as all of the others).

Comment: Can you please clarify "If the moment of the weight of the blocks acts anticlockwise about this point then the tower will topple."

Comment: @Monai Friction between the tower and the plane acts through the pivot point, so we can ignore that. So the only external forces on the tower that have a non-zero moment about the pivot point are the normal force from the slope and the tower's weight. The normal force always has an anticlockwise moment about the pivot point. If the tower's weight also has an anticlockwise moment about the pivot point then there is a non-zero net moment about the pivot point and the tower will rotate anticlockwise and topple.

Comment: Wouldn't the normal force too have zero moment since it acts at the pivot point?

Comment: @gandalf61 Thank you for your explaination! I understand now.

Comment: @RaghavGupta Only if the tower is about to topple. But if the tower is in stable equilibrium then the normal force acts to the right of the pivot point and has a non-zero anticlockwise moment, which is balanced by the clockwise moment of the tower's weight.